# babel not trans compiling the files inside node_modules even with babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I was getting this error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)

So I configured .babelrc with

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    
}
```

While this resolved the issue in all the files, it couldn't for the ones which are inside `node_modules`

So I read some of the answers and it was recommended to change from .babelrc to babel.config.js to include all the directory including node_modules.

so I renamed .babelrc to babel.config.js with the following snippet:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
    
};
```

However the issue still persists.